# Sudden error with Django 'python manage.py runserver'

Tags: python, django

Recently I started a Django project, created a model, then registered it in `admin.py` in the same app file.  I then got this strange error:

```
(djangoEnv) C:\Users\*****\sample_project>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\roanr\sample_project\projects\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    admin.site.register(project)
  File "C:\Users\*****\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 117, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Here's the model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class project():
    title       = models.TextField()
    githubLink  = models.TextField(default="No Github link.")
```

Why is it doing this, and how can it be fixed?
FYI: it does the same thing with `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.
Thanks a lot to anyone who knows what's going on.

Comment: You forgot to subclass `models.Model` in your `project` class. Note also that it's normal practise to use CamelCase for class names in Python.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose the title didn't show when searching Django.  Also, just so I'm not confused, I thought camelCase wasLikeThis, and PascelCase WasLikeThis.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, PascalCase is indeed the right terminology.